# Future prediction: if this happens... it will have... (future perfect tense)

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect

Let's say global warming will hit its peak by 2020 (warmest earth). You want to say this in English, your prediction goes like this:

> If global warming continues to the future, by 2020, **it will have reached** its peak, I believe.

This is only an estimation, meaning not sure. Am I correct to use "will have+participle" (present future) or should I use "would"? -using "would" may fit more as for the prediction thing is concern, BUT, from what I know, there is no such thing as "would have+participle" when you want to express something that will happen in the future. Right?

Comment: Why do you want to use "would"? It implies a possible other outcome, which you don't have. For example, you could say "It *would* have reached its peak if people stopped driving cars."

Comment: What? I'd like to believe your sentence, but it seems illogical, have a look at yours. Also, your answer didn't answer my question, you just throw in another question to me. Sry man.

Comment: Basically, you wrote "should I use *would*"? You should explain the reason why in your question.

Comment: I see, I've edited it just now.

Comment: OK, the wording of you question is still a bit confusing, but I answered based on what I think you are looking for.

Comment: If GW continues, it will reach a peak in x. If GW continued, it would reach a peak in x. By the time GW has peaked, I will have kicked the bucket. :)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify a bit:

> If global warming continues into the future, by 2020 it **will have** reached its peak.

*will have* is correct because the statement describes a period of time between now and 2020. So future perfect is the correct tense for this statement.
The result is certain, as long as the *if* condition is met. And there is no conflicting information regarding the "peak".

If you write:

> If global warming continues into the future, by 2020 it **would have** reached its peak.

the problem is that *would* implies a possibility, so there needs to be both a "it happens" and "it doesn't happen". So adding a "it doesn't happen", you could write:

> If global warming continues into the future, by 2020 it **would have** reached its peak. **However, the prediction proved false** after 5 volcanoes erupted in 2019.

Comment: will have reached, though, is not present perfect....It's actually: future perfect....:)

Comment: Thx for the answer, one thing, why is that my preposition "to" is wrong and you've changed that into "into"?

Comment: It's not wrong, just better. Think of "moving *into* the future" which indicates passage/movement, vs. "moving *to* the future" which doesn't. now --> future